# Zend Framework 2 ZF tool creating controller

Tags: zend-framework2, zend-tool

When I try to create a new controller in my Zend Framework 2.4 application, using the following ZF Tool command:

```
zf create controller Author index-action-included=1 Author C:\wamp\www\ZendApp
```

I get the following error:

```
Reason for failure: Invalid arguments or no arguments provided
```

But when I remove `index-action-included=1`, ZF Tool creates a controller without any problems.

What I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to create the index action, it is created by default. However if you don't want to create it I think it should be something like this:

```
zf create controller Author Author C:\wamp\www\ZendApp 0
```